# When named ES6 exports are asynchronously mutated, why is the change picked up by importers?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

Consider the following example:

```js
// module.mjs

export let member = "initial"

setTimeout(() => { 
  member = "mutated" 
}, 2000)
```

```js
// index.mjs

import { member } from "./module.mjs"

setInterval(() => { 
  console.log(member) 
}, 300);
```

If you run `index.mjs` it prints `"initial"` a few times and after the 2-second timeout starts printing `"mutated"`.

This is surprising to me. I expected it to just keep printing `"initial"` since the reference to `member` has changed. I wouldn't be surprised if my `index.mjs` looked like this

```js
// index.mjs

import * as allExports from "./module.mjs"

setInterval(() => { 
  console.log(allExports.member) 
}, 300);
```

The reference to `allExports` hasn't changed. So by accessing `member` as a property I have access to the new reference. And fair enough, this produces the same result.

But why does it also work in the first case? Are import references updated every time the context for a function call is constructed? Well, then it should also work with default-exports. However, after adjusting the code like this:

```js
// module.mjs

let member = "initial"

export default member

setTimeout(() => { 
  member = "mutated" 
}, 2000)
```

```js
// index.mjs

import member from "./module.mjs"

setInterval(() => { 
  console.log(member) 
}, 300);
```

`index.mjs` just keeps printing `"initial"` according to my intuition. Hmm, maybe there is a fundamental difference between default-exports and named-exports. What if I do this:

```js
// module.mjs

export let member = "initial"

setTimeout(() => { 
  member = "mutated" 
}, 2000)
```

```js
// index.mjs

import * as allExports from "./module.mjs"

let { member } = allExports

setInterval(() => { 
  console.log(member) 
}, 300);
```

Wow, it keeps printing `"initial"`. This is where I got really confused. I always assumed that

```js
import { member } from "./module.mjs"
```

is just short for importing all `named-exports` as an object and then doing destructuring.

So my question is: what underlying principle justifies this unique behavior of `named-exports`?

Comment: Step 1 when fundamentals confuse you: give the official spec a quick read through to see if you simply misunderstood the mechanism. Even something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export will do: "_The export statement is used when creating JavaScript modules to export live bindings to functions, objects, or primitive values from the module_".

Comment: (With Minusfour explaining why allExports does something different with a link to the spec)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is because technically ES6 modules export and import bindings and not values. When you do:

```
export let test = 0
```

You need to think that you are exporting `test` not `0`. That means any change on the variable will be reflected on their imports.

The reason this keeps printing `initial`:

```
// index.mjs

import * as allExports from "./module.mjs"

let { member } = allExports

setInterval(() => { 
  console.log(member) 
}, 300);
```

Is because `allExports` [is a special object](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-module-namespace-exotic-objects). You are creating a new binding here and the value gets copied but you are losing the imported binding.

Comment: Interesting. How come this doesn't apply to default-exports though?

Comment: That I do not know of. My guess is that they wanted to maintain a compatibility layer with other modules (like node modules) that do not export bindings but a sole value. They do have a local name though according to the spec.

Comment: And actually, you can have a default export with a binding. If the default export is a function declaration (with async, generator or a combination of both) or a class declaration, you do export the binding of said declaration. Those are also mutable so it works.